# Memory leak using Autofac with EF Core 3.1 (after migration from 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm experiencing a memory leak when using an EF Core 3.1.5 (after migration from 2.2) with Autofac 5.2.0. My scenario is that on the home page I load some list of products and each reload of a page increase the amount of memory used by 5-10mb, memory increase endlessly. It never goes down. I suspect that my registration is wrong(?) or this is because of tracking behavior in EF Core(?). I try to Register my `MyDbContext` as follows:

```cs
public class DbContextModule<TContext> : Module
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        builder
            .RegisterType<TContext>()
            .WithParameter("options", DbContextOptionsFactory.Get<TContext>())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

public class DbContextOptionsFactory
{
    public static DbContextOptions<TContext> Get<TContext>() where TContext : DbContext
    {
        var confSql = "fake";

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>();
        DbContextConfigurer.Configure<TContext>(builder, confSql);

        return builder.Options;
    }
}

public class DbContextConfigurer
{
    public static void Configure<TContext>(DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext> builder, string connectionString) where TContext : DbContext
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
        {
            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 3,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
        });
    }
}
```

and in a startup file:

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    ...
    builder.RegisterModule<DbContextModule<MyDbContext>>();
    ...
}
```

I try to add `AsSelf` or `ExternallyOwned` but nothing changed.
I also try to register DbContext via Microsoft DI but nothing changed.
Try to use `AddDbContextPool` on `ServiceCollection` but still without success.

Above problems don't occur when EF Core 2.2 was used.

Comment: What do you think `.AsSelf()
            .ExternallyOwned()` do?

Comment: Which Memory Profiler have you used to identify what types are leaking?

Comment: There is no evidence as yet there is a memory leak, task manager is not a good way of determining such issues

Comment: @TheGeneral after 10 minutes of using an app on test environment I got DependencyResolutionException -> OutOfMemoryException. The note about 5/10mb per request I observed locally and I know that Activity Manager is not a good way of determining such issues, but I treat it rather as a confirmation of what I saw on test environment.

Comment: I see, this is where you want to use a memory profiler, this will give you the ammunition you need to know what is being leaked if any, or whats being over allocated.

Comment: @TheGeneral I thought maybe there could be some known issues around that when migrating from EF Core 2.2 to 3.1 so I would not need a profiler :/.  Gonna check then in a memory profiler and edit question later.

Comment: How does the code on your page (controller) look?

Comment: Try to create a small reproducible example and it would be much easier to help you. It is hard to say what the problem might be otherwise.

Comment: @Magnus and TheGeneral thanks for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some investigation via DotMemory, I saw that I have some big peak of memory usage via ServiceProviderCache. When I try to google `ServiceProviderCache EF Core` I found following [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10211).

In my situation, the problem was that I enable the console logging locally to easier spot problems with ef core after migration. The DbContext looks like this:

```cs
private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
{
    _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole());
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    if (``it is a local run``)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}
```

the problematic lines were:

```cs
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
            : base(options)
{
    _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole());
}
```

Based on the answer on GitHub, the logger was created each time the DbContext was created and it wasn't destroyed after that. The solution would be to have a static logger. So I refactor it as follows:

Create ConsoleLogger:

```cs
public class ConsoleLogger
{
    public readonly ILoggerFactory Instance;

    public ConsoleLogger()
    {
        Instance = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.Create(x => x.AddConsole());
    }
}
```

Register it as a singleton:

```cs
...
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
...
```

and use it in DbContext like that:

```cs
public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options, ConsoleLogger consoleLogger)
            : base(options) =>
    _consoleLogger = consoleLogger;

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

    if (``it is a local run``)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseLoggerFactory(_consoleLogger.Instance)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}
```

Thanks to above the memory profiling chart goes from this:
[image]
[image]
to this:
[image]

Comment: Good investigation. I'm sure this will be helpful for future readers.